# Triangularise a matrix

Tags: matrices

How do I find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is upper triangular?

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-3 & 1 & -1\\-7 & 5 & -1\\-6 & 6 & -2\end{pmatrix}$$

I can't really find a good general method for doing this online.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form Is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you wanted a computational platform then wolfram Alpha can be of help.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristc+polynomial+of+matrix+%7B%7B-3,1,-1%7D,%7B-7,5,-1%7D,%7B-6,6,-2%7D%7D

From that link we find that the Characteristic polynomial of that Matrix is having roots in the Field $\mathbf{R}$ so therefore it  is triangulable in that Field.

It has Eigen values $4,-2,-2$ .

So the Eigen vector coresponding to 4 can be taken as first vector $v_1$ in the basis and then find a vector $v_2$ whose image under $A$ lies in the subspace spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ make sure they are linearly independent.

Then atlast take the characteristic vector of the eigen value 2 $v_3$ so you get a basis.

Comment: That's not true. Take any Jordan block with real diagonal and the result you claim fails

Comment: Hi  José Alejandro Aburto Araneda I'm stating the Result from Hoffman Kunze page 203.Theorem 5 . I don't fully understand your  objection

Comment: @JoséAlejandroAburtoAraneda Hey refer to Hoffman kunze page 203,Theorem 5.Chapter 6

Comment: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable, and its characteristic polynomial have real roots. The theorem you are "using" talks about the **minimal polynomial** not the characteristic polynomial